# Use Arduino library on raspberry

Tags: hardware, sensor, arduino

I am not sure whether this is a stupid question or not, but you may be able to help.

I bought a sensor board and the manufacturer provides an Arduino-library to use the sensor.

Is there a way for me to use this libraries on my pi?

Comment: It would be helpful if you also told us, what sensor you are referring to, and which library.

Comment: Its this sensor [http://www.exp-tech.de/Sensoren/MinIMU-9-v2-Gyro-Accelerometer-and-Compass-L3GD20-and-LSM303DLHC-Carrier.html] and there are several collections of code provided to use the sensor with Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the sensor talks I2C it should not be too hard to port the library. Otherwise there seems to be others that already have done this, such as [minimu9-ahrs](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/minimu9-ahrs).